# Why are these two same functions creating two output process?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I tried to check the validity of my functions and I noticed that two of my functions which have the same code are giving two different outputs. I need to change the if-conditional in one of them but I also need to make sure that both of them works properly. Can

```
data_out = open("mentees_all_attributes.csv", "rU")
reader = csv.reader(data_out)
next(reader,None)


def primaryWithParticipatedCounts(jobs, count):
    for line in reader:  
        cells = line
        new_cell = cells[0], cells[6], cells[7], cells[8], cells[9], cells[
            10]  # name, # of participation, primary occupation/industry, secondary occupation/industry
        if int(new_cell[1]) > 0:  # Isolate all the participants with more than 0
            primary = new_cell[2]
            if primary == jobs:
                count += 1

    return jobs, count

print primaryWithParticipatedCounts(A012,a012counts)


def primaryWithoutParticipatedCounts(jobs, count):
    for line in reader:  
        cells = line
        new_cell = cells[0], cells[6], cells[7], cells[8], cells[9], cells[
            10]  
        if int(new_cell[1]) > 0:  
            primary = new_cell[2]
            if primary == jobs:
                count += 1

    return jobs, count

print primaryWithoutParticipatedCounts(A012,a012counts)
```

the return output is:

```
('[A012]', 3)
('[A012]', 0)
```

Comment: You are reusing the same reader, but once the reader is read, there is nothing more to read from the reader, so the second method has nothing to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your two functions seem to be the same (unless I overlooked something). The problem seems to be with the `reader`. A reader, like any file handle, is an `iterator`, and once you've iterated all the lines in the reader, it is exhausted. Thus, when you use *the same* `reader` *again* for the second function, there are no more lines to read, and `count` ends up as `0`.

You could try any of the following:

- open the file and *within* the function, instead of reusing the same reader twice
- read the lines into a list: `lines = list(reader)`; only advisable for small files!
- rewind the file handle to the start before using the reader again: `data_out.seek(0)`

Comment: For the first solution I keep getting:

TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, tuple found

and the file is too big for the second solution where the third solution gives:

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10

Comment: nevermind sorry, the 3rd solution did work, I just had to make a variable an integer, I needed to add reader = csv.reader(data_out) next(reader,None) again

Comment: @peaceandiago I think you should be able to keep using the old `reader` when you use `seek`, but you will have to skip the first line again.

Answer (score 0):

```
data_out.seek(0) between the funcs
```

Comment: doing data_out.seek creates a ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10

Comment: sorry, you're right, but because I had to make a variable an integer, I needed to add reader = csv.reader(data_out)
next(reader,None) again